# Android: remove shadow from bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

When placing a container below my bottom navigation, it is partly covered by the gray shadow from the navigation, even after adding content to the container. How do I remove the shadow?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try to set elevation as 0.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use **`app:elevation="0dp"`** to hide shadow from from bottom navigation

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

Comment: this will also remove the elevation on the top side of the bottom nav view

Comment: Soo clutch my friend. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using above Api-level 28 you can use

```
android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
```