# How to remove bottom navigation shadow

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

As i show in image below i want to remove the shadow of bottomnavigation . 
[image]

I try below solution and find noun of them useful :

[Android: remove shadow from bottom navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404774/android-remove-shadow-from-bottom-navigation)

here is my xml file :

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
    app:menu="@menu/botton_navigation_menu"
    android:layout_above="@+id/phone_frame"
    android:elevation="0dp"/>
```

Comment: share your xml file

Comment: question updated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `app:elevation` instead of `android:elevation`

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in onCreate() method

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```